# MinGW-w64 g++ does not produce executable file

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw-w64

I'm trying to use MinGW-w64 g++ to compile my program but it does not produce a single file, nor any std output.

Using the WSL I can compile the same code successfully.

The following is my main.cxx:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With the WSL I use the following command:

```
g++ -g src/main.cxx
```

Which produces a working a.out file.

With MinGW-w64 g++, I use the following command in Powershell (both normal and Administrator):

```
D:\SDK\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\g++.exe -g .\src\main.cxx
```

This does not produce a file and also takes far less time that the WSL g++.

With the "-v" flag I get:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=D:\SDK\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=D:/SDK/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-8.1.0/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw32 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw810/i686-810-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw810/i686-810-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw810/i686-810-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/c/mingw810/i686-810-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/c/mingw810/i686-810-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/opt/lib -L/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw810/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/lib -Wl,--large-address-aware'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 D:/SDK/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix D:/SDK/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/ -D_REENTRANT .\src\main.cxx -quiet -dumpbase main.cxx -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase main -g -version -o C:\Users\Jobasha\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKgE3Ma.s
```

Which doesn't mean a whole lot to me!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you didn't install via MSYS2, the likely culprit was something you didn't do correctly during the install. It looks like you didn't bother adding to your PATH, if I had to judge based on your call the mingw g++.

Comment: I have reinstalled using MSYS2 and it now works. Thanks for the help!